# How can I use 'git add' command on a file whose path includes a directory with spaces

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I'm trying to use Git Add command to stage a couple of files for committing later. However, I can't seem to add it because Git bash doesn't like a directory with spaces in it. How can get around this issue?

I'm using Win 7 OS. My command looks like the one below:

```
git add folder1/folder2/new folder/folder3/myFile.txt
```

The error that I'm getting is the following:
new: No such file or directory

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried quoting the filename and path?  `git add "folder1/folder2/new folder/folder3/myFile.txt"`

Comment: Yes, that was just what James suggested. And it works great. I had no idea you can even do that. haha

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to get around this problem if you put the path in quotes:

```
git add "folder1/folder2/new folder/folder3/myFile.txt"
```